# Н в причастиях

Tags: орфография, причастия

Сколько Н пишется в причастиях, типа "сделанны" и какое на этот счет существует правило?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В страдательных причастиях прошедшего времени пишется удвоенное Н.
Примеры: *выполненный, утомленный, раскрашенный*

Answer (score 2):

но в кратких причастиях всегда пишется одна Н, поэтому все-таки сделаны

Answer (score 1):

Слово **сделаны** пишется с одной буквой Н, так как существует правило, в котором написа**Н**о, что краткие страдательные причастия всегда пишутся с одной Н. Слово **сделаны** является кратким страдательным причастием, а его полное причастие –– сделанные. Примеры:

1. Красные мокасины были сделаны в Китае.
2. Недавно сделанные мокасины были проданы.

Надеюсь, понятно.

Comment: Всё понятно, но есть небольшое замечание: не каждое слово, похожее на краткое причастие, является кратким причастием. Не надо забывать о парных вариантах, например: выводы обоснованы научными фактами – выводы точны и обоснованны.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что во втором варианте краткие прилагательные у Вас? ;)

Comment: А вы в этом сомневаетесь?

Answer (score 0):

Н и НН в причастиях
и отглагольных прилагательных

НН пишется в страдательных причастиях прошедшего времени:
если причастия образованы от приставочных глаголов: вы-читанная рукопись, на-клеенная картинка, по-крашенный забор, про-йденный путь, про-смотренный фильм;

если причастия имеют при себе зависимое слово: недавно кошенный луг, три года тому назад писанная картина, крашенная маляром крыша, мощенная булыжником дорога;

если причастия образованы от бесприставочных глаголов совершенного вида: брошенный (бросить), данный (дать), казненный (казнить), купленный (купить), лишенный (лишить), плененный (пленить). 
Н пишется в отглагольных прилагательных:
если прилагательные образованы от глаголов несовершенного вида (не имеющих приставок, не содержащих суффиксов -ованн-, -ёванн-): белёный дом (белить - глагол несовершенного вида), бешеная собака, вареный картофель, вороненая сталь, каленый штык, сушеная ягода;

если прилагательные не имеют при себе зависимого слова: крашеный пол (но: крашенный масляной краской пол), груженая баржа (но: груженная песком баржа).

Примечание. Разграничение страдательных причастий и отглагольных прилагательных в некоторых случаях осуществляется не только по наличию или отсутствию приставок и зависимых слов, но и по смыслу. Например, и словосочетаниях то'пленная печь и топлёный жир признаки, обозначаемые словами то'пленная и топлёный, разно го свойства: в первом случае сохраняется глагольное значение (налицо временной предел), т. е. определение выражено причастием; во втором случае назван признак постоянный (ср. также: топлёное молоко, топлёное масло), т. е. определение выражено прилагательным. Смысловое различие наблюдается и в таких предложениях: Будучи раненным, командир еще отдавал приказания (слово будучи вносит временное значение в форму раненным, усиливая тем самым ее глагольность). - На опушке показались солдаты, выносившие убитых и раненых товарищей (признак обозначен прилагательным).

В кратких страдательных причастиях, в отличие от полных, пишется Н, в кратких отглагольных прилагательных, как и в отыменных, пишется НН:

при кратком причастии имеется (или мыслится) существительное в форме творительного падежа со значением деятеля; ср.: Территория около нового дома еще не благоустроена (причастие). - Территория около нового дома была мала, неблагоустроенна (прилагательное); Сыновьям всегда везло, и они были избалованы судьбой (причастие). - Сыновья были капризны и избалованны (прилагательное); Статья начитана для записи на пленку (причастие). - Девушка была музыкальна и начитанна (прилагательное); Население было взволновано сообщением по радио. - Море сегодня взволнованно;

краткие страдательные причастия употребляютсяв конструкциях с зависимым инфинитивом: Студентка намерена отвечать на вопрос; с зависимым дополнением: Спортсмены были уверены в победе; (но: Броски баскетболистов были точны и уверенны — без дополнения).

Примечание 1. Некоторые отглагольные прилагательные в краткой форме пишутся с н (если они образованы от приставочных глаголов, что сближает их с причастиями): Глаза у нее были заплаканы (ср.: заплаканные глаза); Пальто его было поношено (поношенное пальто).

Примечание 2. В существительных и наречиях, образованных от причастий и отглагольных прилагательных, пишется столько н, сколько их было в производящей основе: воспитанник (воспитанный), избранник (избранный), священник (священный), ставленник (ставленный) (об образовании слова "ставленник" см. "Суффиксы прилагательных, образованных от глаголов", пр. 1), вареник (вареный), копчености (копченый), мученик (мученый), мороженое (из прилагательного мороженое - морозить); организованно входить (организованный), путано отвечать (путаный), удивленно смотреть (удивленный).